# intrinsic calibration of the kinect cameras

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do the tutorial in http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration?action=show&redirect=openni_camera%2Fcalibration

3.RGB camera

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw camera:=/camera/rgb --size 5x4 --square 0.0245

I commit my successful calibration

and

4.IR(depth)camera

rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py image:=/camera/ir/image_raw camera:=/camera/ir --size 5x4 --square 0.0245

I also commit my successful calibration

Question.

1. How can I know the calibration result?
2. How can I compare the before calibration?

(Should I see a noticeable difference when viewing the raw and rectified images?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36582/intrinsic-calibration-of-the-kinect-cameras/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can view the yaml file

```
$ ls ~/.ros/camera_info/
depth_B00362708888047B.yaml  rgb_B00362708888047B.yaml
```

Perhaps it is possible seen that you have less distortion round the edges of your image?

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0